# Proving an algebraic identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove:

$$(a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) - abc = (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)$$

Problem:

I am not sure how to proceed after expanding the brackets on the RHS. I am not sure if I also expanded correctly. My solution is:

Comment: I think you forgot to actually post anything after "My solution is:" :P

Comment: After expanding the RHS, expand the LHS and compare.

Comment: @KoA, prolly a master in keeping people in suspense.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting $a+b+c=x$. Then consider
\begin{align}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) &= (x-a)(x^{2}-(b+c)x+bc)\\
                &= x^{3}-(b+c)x^{2}+bcx-ax^{2}+ax(b+c)-abc\\
                &= x^{3}-x^{2}(a+b+c)+x(ab+bc+ac)-abc\\
\end{align}
note that
$$x^{3}-x^{2}(a+b+c)=0$$

A little rearrangement will give you the identity you seek.

Comment: you have a -x() that should be +x() in your next-to-last line

Comment: @hkBst Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 5):

Both sides are homogeneous polynomials in $a,b,c$ with degree $3$. You may check they agree at $1,1,1$ and that the LHS vanishes at $a+b=0$, $a+c=0$, $b+c=0$ (to check one condition is enough, by symmetry) to have they are the same polynomial. But if $a+b=0$

$$(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-abc = c(ab)-abc =0$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca+b^2)(c+a)$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca)(a+c)+ab^2+b^2c$$
Adding $abc$ gives:
$$(ab+bc+ca)(a+c)+ab^2+b^2c+abc$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca)(a+c)+b(ab+bc+ac)$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)$$

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)−abc$

P1

$f(a) = (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)−abc$

$f(-b) = c(-b^2 + bc -bc) - cb^2 = 0$

Like wise symmetrically

a+b,b+c,c+a are factors

You can use the symmetry argument and claim that these are the only factors

Or you can go down the path of expand and factoring again

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solutions of Jack D'Aurizio and sidt36:

Consider each side as a function of $a$:
$$L(x) = (x + b + c)(xb + bc + cx) - xbc$$
$$R(x) = (x + b)(b + c)(c + x)$$

They are both quadratic, and so can be expressed as $A(x-r)(x-s)$ (where $r,s$ in general may be complex).
But it is easily verified that $$L(-b) = R(-b) = 0\\L(-c) = R(-c) = 0\\L(0) = R(0) = bc(b+c)$$
from which we see that $r = -b, s = -c, A = b+c$ for both, and therefore they are equal.